# Multiple dropdown through ng-option not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

We are making multiple dropdown through `ng-options` in a form but if we change one dropdown the selected value is assgined to the other dropdown as well.

```
<div ng-app="SelectApp">
    <div ng-controller="selectController">

    <select name="category-group" id="categoryGroup" class="form-control" ng-model="itemSelected" ng-change="onCategoryChange(itemSelected)" 
    ng-options="category.name group by category.group for category in categories"> 
    </select>

    <select name="category-group" id="categoryGroup2" class="form-control" ng-model="itemSelected"  ng-change="onCategoryChange(itemSelected)" 
    ng-options="category.name group by category.group for category in categories">
    </select>

</div>
```

JS code:

```
'use strict';
var app = angular.module('SelectApp', [ ]);
app.controller('selectController', ['$scope', '$window', function ($scope, $window) {
    $scope.categories = [       
      { id: 0, name: "Select a category..."},
        { id: 1, name: "Cars", group : "- Vehicles -" },
       { id: 2, name: "Commercial vehicles", disabled: false,group : "- Vehicles -" },
       { id: 3, name: "Motorcycles", disabled: false, group : "- Vehicles -"  },
       { id: 4, name: "Car & Motorcycle Equipment", disabled: false,
       group : "- Vehicles -" },
       { id: 5, name: "Boats", disabled: false, group : "- Vehicles -"  },
       { id: 6, name: "Other Vehicles", disabled: false, group : "- Vehicles -"  },
       { id: 7, name: "Appliances", disabled: false , group : "- House and Children -" },
       { id: 8, name: "Inside", disabled: false,group : "- House and Children -"  },
       { id: 9, name: "Games and Clothing", disabled: false,group : "- House and Children -"  },
       { id: 10, name: "Garden", disabled: false,group : "- House and Children -"  }
    ];

    $scope.itemSelected = $scope.categories[0];

    $scope.onCategoryChange = function () {
        $window.alert("Selected Value: " + $scope.itemSelected.id + "\nSelected Text: " + $scope.itemSelected.name);

    };
}]);
```

Comment: You are using the same ng-model for two dropdowns, So angular update the value to its model. (ng-model="itemSelected" )

Comment: use separate models for each select box

Comment: thanks for the quick response, but these dropdown  are coming from ng-repeat from some backend system. I want to assgin to different value to different dropdown in alert

Comment: both are showing category name as value, is there any way to append numbers at the end of your ng-model as did in the id of select box

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sensex00007/mLrynxh2/186/   for demo

Comment: i have applied the suggestion provided by you and its working fine, but if you see in the alert messages it is still taking selected text as the value of first drop down selected 
http://jsfiddle.net/sensex00007/mLrynxh2/187/

Comment: update your fiddle. and upvote if worked.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mLrynxh2/188/ - check now I updated the fiddle. If worked Up vote

Comment: kindly check when u select the value from dropdown the alert messages not getting change when you select the value from second dropdown

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151415/discussion-between-ashu-and-sami).

Answer (score 1):

I changed your code as follows. Hope this will work.

app.js

```
$scope.itemSelected = $scope.categories[0];
$scope.itemSelected1 = $scope.categories[0];
$scope.onCategoryChange = function (item,index) {

    $window.alert("Selected Value: " + item.id + "\nSelected Text: " + item.name);

};
}]);
```

view

```
<div ng-app="SelectApp">
<div ng-controller="selectController">

<select name="category-group" id="categoryGroup" class="form-control" ng-model="itemSelected"                                          ng-change="onCategoryChange(itemSelected)" 
    ng-options="category.name group by category.group for category in categories">

</select>

<select name="category-group" id="categoryGroup" class="form-control" ng-model="itemSelected1"                                          ng-change="onCategoryChange(itemSelected1)" 
    ng-options="category.name group by category.group for category in categories">

</select>

</div>
```

Comment: hi srin ,thanks for your help but still my problem has not been resolved I am updating my fiddler, when i select from first dropdown the value which i am binding in xyz its correct showing but when i select from second dropdown its updating the first and second both with same value i want its diffrent value selcting individually 
http://jsfiddle.net/sensex00007/mLrynxh2/205/

Comment: Updated check your fiddle